# Inserting rows in UITableView upon click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, custom-cell

I'm having trouble adding rows to the `UITableView` upon `UIButton` click.

I have two custom-cell xibs - one that contains an `UILabel`, another one that contains an `UIButton`.

Data for the table cell is loaded from two dictionaries (`answersmain` and `linesmain`).

Here is the code for the `UITableView` main functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.linesmain["Audi"]!.count + 1
}


// 3
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    if(indexPath.row < 3){
        var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell

        cell.lblCarName.text = linesmain["Audi"]![indexPath.row]

        return cell

    } else  {
      var celle:vwAnswers = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! vwAnswers
        celle.Answer.setTitle(answersmain["Good car"]![0], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

                return celle
    }}
```

What do I put here?

```
@IBAction func option1(sender: UIButton) {

// I need to add rows to the uitableview from two dictionaries into two different xibs 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the next:

```
var showingAll = false

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return showingAll ? self.linesmain["Audi"]!.count + 1 : 0
}

@IBAction func option1(sender: UIButton) {
    showingAll = true

    tableView.beginUpdates()

    let insertedIndexPathRange = 0..<self.linesmain["Audi"]!.count + 1
    var insertedIndexPaths = insertedIndexPathRange.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) }
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: tried the code. actually, it returns empty tableview.

Comment: empty tableview after tapping the button ?

Comment: after launching the app

Comment: unless i change  `return showingAll ? self.linesmain["Audi"]!.count + 1 : 0` the last zero to any bigger int value. and then it crashes on `tableView.endUpdates( )` @sgl0v

Comment: the crash log is `incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed` @sgl0v

Comment: With this approach you should get the empty table view from the startup and insert cells with fade animation by tapping on the button.

Comment: unfortunately, the button is inside the the second custom cell xib, which doesn't load up

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look over the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

There is this `UITableView` method called `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` that inserts row at a specified indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `linesmain` and `answersmain` by adding data to these and then call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

It would be better if you extract `linesmain["Audi"]` and `answersmain["Good car"]` and save them into different mutable arrays and modify those.

You need to do this in the `func option1`.